# FTP using Tor Browser Bundle

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

Is it anonymous if I try to connect to a clearnet FTP server over Tor Browser with a username and password, assuming the username and password does not contain my identity?

Will it leak my IP or other information about me like BitTorrenting does?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's safe. Keep in mind that you need to use enforced "passive FTP" mode because you will have only one-way connection originating from you via Tor, so both data and command streams are obliged to be inside this one connection. FTP - instead of BitTorrent - talks **just** to the server it is connecting to in the way you're exactly told it to do so, and that makes it safe.

Answer (score 1):

It is not safe to use ftp over TOR. It will not leak your IP, but ftp is a clear-text-protocol. So your ftp username and password can easily be sniffed from the TOR exit node - using tcpdump or similar tools.